# How to create Custom UITableViewCell with dynamic number of labels

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

each custom cell in tableview can either have one or two or three or more labels depending on the number of data return from api.

I've tried creating dynamic number of labels into cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath method. But every time I scroll, all these labels overlap each other..Is there any other way to create a dynamic number of labels into a cell?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PracLabelCell", for: indexPath) as! PracLabelCell

    let w : CGFloat = CGFloat(self.tableview.frame.size.width/3)
    var x : CGFloat = 0

    for index in 0...2
    {
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: x, y: cell.frame.origin.y, width: w , height: cell.frame.size.height))
        let str = String(index)
        print(str)
        label.text = str
        cell.contentView.addSubview(label)
        print("x is" , x)
        x += w

    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Could you try to use constraints? Also you can use layout if need before return cell, perhaps it’s can help.

Comment: Better to go with nested table view or collection view and you can try collection view inside a table view cell?

Answer (score 1):

Use constraints to increase the height of the cells. Add a vertical stackview in the cell. And create a function in cell class to append labels based on argument values.

```
class PracLabelCell: UITableViewCell {
    let titleLabel = UILabel()
    let stackView = UIStackView()
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(titleLabel)

        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        stackView.alignment = .fill
        stackView.spacing = 2
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(stackView)

        titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        titleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        titleLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true

        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLabel.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    func setup(names: [String]) {
        stackView.arrangedSubviews.forEach { stackView.removeArrangedSubview($0);$0.removeFromSuperview() }
        names.forEach {
            let label = UILabel()
            label.text = $0
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(label)
        }
    }
}
```

And pass the values in `tableView cellForRowAt` method.

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var namesArray = [["a","b","c"],["d","e"],["f"],["g","h"],[],["j"]]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        tableView.register(PracLabelCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "PracLabelCell")
    }
    // MARK: - Table view data source
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return namesArray.count
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PracLabelCell", for: indexPath) as! PracLabelCell
        cell.titleLabel.text = "This cell has \(namesArray[indexPath.row].count) labels"
        cell.setup(names: namesArray[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: when adding more names in array it overlap the first label of each cell..can you please solve this issue?

Comment: @user11410114_riz _"when adding more names in array it overlap the first label of each cell."_ Did you try my answer

Comment: just add more name like this and than see the output var namesArray = [["a","b","c"],["d","e"],["f"],["g","h"],[],["j"],["a","b","c"],["d","e"],["f"],["g","h"],[],["j"],["a","b","c"],["d","e"],["f"],["g","h"],[],["j"],["a","b","c"],["d","e"],["f"],["g","h"],[],["j"]]

Comment: @user11410114_riz Solved. Change `stackView.arrangedSubviews.forEach { stackView.removeArrangedSubview($0) }` to `stackView.arrangedSubviews.forEach { stackView.removeArrangedSubview($0);$0.removeFromSuperview() }` in `setup(names` method. Check updated answer

Comment: @user11410114_riz Accept the answer if it works. `stackView.removeArrangedSubview($0);$0.removeFromSuperview()` Is used to remove each exiting label before adding new labels.

Comment: Is it possible to arrange labels not vertically, but horizontally, i.e. next to each other with a spacer?

Answer (score 0):

> you need to create inner tableview inside cell its more better than loop and create label manually.
>   you just need to create tableview inside your main cell. for inner tableview create cell with label thats it now you can return number of cells as you want.
>   hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

if in your cell you didn't add any label in your `.xib` file.
then try this

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PracLabelCell", for: indexPath) as! PracLabelCell

let w : CGFloat = CGFloat(self.tableview.frame.size.width/3)
var x : CGFloat = 0
for subView in cell.contentView.subviews{
     if subView.isKind(of: UILabel.self){
         return cell
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using a UIStackview. Here is the sample code for a view controller that has a tableview whose each row can show 1, 2 or 3 labels. The cellForRow datasource method has the logic to switch the count of lables according to the requirement.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // This array contains the sample data to populate the tableview. Each 
       element dictates the number of labels to be shown in the cell
    var tableData = [1,2,3,2,3,2]
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: 
Int) -> Int {
        return tableData.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LabelRow", 
for: indexPath) as! LabelTableViewCell

        let labelCount = tableData[indexPath.row]

        // Check the label count for the current row to decide how many labels to show.
        // Extra lables are hidden
        switch labelCount {
        case 1:
            cell.label1.isHidden = false
            cell.label2.isHidden = true
            cell.label3.isHidden = true
        case 2:
            cell.label1.isHidden = false
            cell.label2.isHidden = false
            cell.label3.isHidden = true
        default:
            cell.label1.isHidden = false
            cell.label2.isHidden = false
            cell.label3.isHidden = false
        }

        return cell
    }
}
```

The LabelTableViewCell class is a subclass of UITableViewCell and it contains a UIStackView. The stack view handles the task of arranging the labels vertically. Also as one or more labels(which are added as arranged subviews of the stack view in Interface Builder) are hidden, the stack view's height gets adjusted. The trick is to have constraints between the stackview's top to the cell's content view's top and similar bottom constraints. This will ensure that when the stackview's height changes, the cell's height also changes accordingly.

I have added the project to [GitHub](https://github.com/MithunMadhav1112/dynamic_height_tableView_cells) for better understanding

Here is a screenshot of the result.

[image]